# Convert an Int into Hexa

Tags: c++, qt

```
QString str = "1228";
QString str1 = str.mid(0,2);
QString str2 = str.mid(2,2);

qDebug() << "str1 : " + str1;
qDebug() << "str2 : " + str2;

int i1 = str1.toInt();
int i2 = str2.toInt();

qDebug() << "i1 : " << i1;
qDebug() << "i2 : " << i2;

QByteArray bA;
bA.append(0x12);
bA.append(0x28);
```

I wonder who can I get the 0x12 and 0x28 hexadecimals only from "1228" if some body can help please.

Comment: hint: 12(dec) != 0x12(hex)

Comment: Yes, but I need to start from "1228" and get two hexadecimals (0x12 and 0x28), as you can see in the params of the append function

Comment: `str1.toInt` converts a decimal to int so obviously it won't work

Comment: Yes I agree with you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't add unrelated language tags. That is considered spamming. C and C are very different languages and your code is not valid C code.

Comment: OK I'm sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

You should use `QByteArray::fromHex()` function, ex :

```
QString szInput = "1218";
QByteArray bA = QByteArray::fromHex( szInput.toLatin1() );

qDebug() << "Hex array : " << bA.toHex().toUpper();
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works for me. I used an other solution as well

Comment: `QString str = "1227";
    bool ok;
    QByteArray bA;

    QString str1 = str.mid(0,2);
    QString str2 = str.mid(2,2);
    bA.append(str1.toUInt(&ok, 16));
    bA.append(str2.toUInt(&ok, 16));`

Comment: Be aware of bigger int value (ex: 6-8 digits), you should handle input error also (impair input string size, etc.)

Comment: Maybe looking at the documentation of [QString::toInt()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt) would have shown you that there is a second parameter where you can specify the base. This would avoid all those useless conversions above.